# How to create multiple & send multiple exchanges in Apache Camel

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel, eip

I have a situation in which I am generating a list of tasks in my camel producer then I need to send multiple exchanges containing each of these single task so that next component can process it.

Is there any pattern or producer in Camel which can serve my purpose.

I know there is DefaultTemplateProducer but my next part in route is processor which doesnot have an endpoint to point to so its of no use to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use the Camel splitter pattern to split the list and send it down the route?

[Apache Camel Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit unclear what you want. Maybe explain your question in more details. Also make sure to understand and read about the Enterprise Integration Patterns that Camel offers: http://camel.apache.org/eip

And as U2one says, the splitter pattern may be a good start accordingly to your question.